# Linear algebra question about a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ not through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing the points $A=(0,1,1)$, $B=(1,-1,1)$, and $C=(1,0,1)$. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the line perpendicular to $\mathcal{P}$, containing the point $A$. Let $U=(1,-1,0)$. Find the following.

1. a scalar equation for the plane $\mathcal{P}$.
2. a vector equation for the line $\mathcal{L}$.
3. The point on the line $\mathcal{L}$ closest to the point $U$.

My approach was to translate the plane in such a way that it ends up crossing the origin, and then translating all the points referred to the same way. Then I translated the answers back.

Is this the correct method? If so, could somebody please give a detailed answer, as there is no solution in the book for this problem. If not so, why is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

(1) A scalar equation looks like $ax+by+cz=d$, so you need to find $a,b,c$ such that $A, B$, and $C$ solve the equation. Hint: it turns out that $d$ can just be $1$, assuming that the plane containing $A,B$, and $C$ is not already going through the origin. So this is just three equations in three variables.

Your approach isn't *wrong*, but you really don't need the translation, given that you can just solve a linear system to get $(a,b,c)$.

I'm not sure if you're having trouble with the other steps, but here's an overview:

(2) Once you have that plane, $(a,b,c)$ is perpendicular to it. So you just have to send a line through $A$ going that direction.

(3) This is just a matter of projecting $U$ onto $\mathcal{L}$, which is really just projecting onto $(a,b,c)$. But $\mathcal{L}$ doesn't go through the origin, so you have to make some point on $\mathcal{L}$ the origin, like $A$.